# How to check the broadcast receiver is running or not in android?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

Hai is it possible to check the broadcast receiver is currently running or not?if possible how to check it?

Comment: what are you trying to do , why or where do you want to check if its running or not

Comment: am checking for getting latitude value,i create a application using broadcast receiver in login form.whenevr i entered the form my receiver is automatically started.But i need to start once

Comment: A `BroadcastReceiver` isn't meant to run permanently. Either register a `BroadcastReceiver` in the manifest allowing it to receive various `Intents` or register/unregister dynamically in your code. If you want to know when (if) it gets triggered then simply use a `Log` method to track it in logcat.

Comment: This is dependent on how you want it to work? When do you register it? When do you unregister it?

Comment: @MisterSquonk i registered dynamically only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check it at runtime you can store a global `boolean` variable and set it to `false` and inside your `onReceive()` set it to `true` and before the `onReceive()` exit set it back to false .
any time you can check this global variable to tell if that broadcast receiver is running or not .

if you mean you want to know if its work or not make a message to the log cat example

```
    onReceive(){
     Log.d("my broadcast","works");
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use dumpsys to help debug this for dynamically registered receivers:

`adb shell dumpsys activity broadcasts`

Use this in combination with grep and breakpoints in the debugger and you can find if your broadcast is registered at a certain time or not.

This is supposed to help with statically registered receivers, but I haven't used it myself:

`adb shell dumpsys package`

Answer (score 1):

A `BroadcastReceiver` is not intended to be running in the background. It'll be woken up and killed in limited scope.